# Presenter: when to start async work with setRetainInstance(true) fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, mosby

The only difference of retained instance in Fragment's lifecycle is that `onCreate()` don't calls. But at this state View isn't inflated yet.

When must I call methods like `loadNews()` of `Presenter` of Fragment with `setRetainInstance(true)`? I want to `loadNews()` only when fresh instance of Fragment was created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it in `Fragment.onViewCreated()` because at this point you can be sure that the UI (View) is initialized and ready to display things (otherwise i.e. presenter calling view.showLoading() would result in a NullPointerException). But you have to ensure by your own that loadingData is only invoked the first time (i.e. check if `bundle == null`)

If you use Mosby's ViewState Feature, then override `onNewViewState()` method and call `presenter.loadData()`. Mosby only ever calls this method on the first time the View appears, so you don't have to check if `bundle == null` by your own.

Comment: Yep, I use Mosby's ViewState. But `bundle == null` after screen rotation when I do `Fragment.setRetainInstance(true)`.

Comment: Then simply use `MvpViewStateFragment.onNewViewState()` and put your `presenter.loadData()` in there. `onNewViewState()` will be called only the first time the Fragment will be created so it's kind of similar to "onFirstTime()"

Comment: Faced with another problem. onNewViewState executed before Views was instantiated. I see the solution by wrapping View's methods code with Handler. Any other ideas?

Comment: This should not be the case. Please report an issue on github's issue tracker. Please write which version of Mosby you use and attach some code. i.e. your Fragment / Presenter's code.
https://github.com/sockeqwe/mosby/issues